# MySQL Selecting a complex sub query as a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have:

```
SELECT tbl_review.*, users.first_name, users.last_name, (
    SELECT order_ns.tran_date 
    FROM order_ns 
    LEFT JOIN product_2_order_ns.external_order_id = order_ns.order_id 
    WHERE product_2_order_ns.bkfno IN :id
    ORDER BY order_ns.trandate ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) as purchase_date
FROM tbl_review
LEFT JOIN users ON users.sequal_user_id = tbl_review.user_id
WHERE tbl_review.product_id IN :id AND tbl_review.approved = 1
```

Which, in its sub query, selects an order the user has which has a product in question (defined in `:id`) get the the oldest transaction date on file for one of the found orders.

I would really like to keep this to one call of the database (don't really want to call again for each returned user for just one field, or even do a range query of all users) but obviously this particular query isn't working.

What can I do, if anything, to get this working?

I cannot make the sub query into a join since they are two distinct pieces of data, the sub query needs to return detail for each row in the main query.

Comment: what is the error. can u make a sqlfiddle for that.

Comment: From my experience the `IN` syntax accept a range of values as an "array" so you should be doing something like `IN ('value1')`. If this is a PDO thing then you need `IN (:id)`. If you are not passing in multiple values then an equal `=` sign will suffice

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I actually have a PDO library that does this for me

Comment: @developerCK The error is that JOINs are not allowed in sub queries I believe, if I take out the sub query it works perfectly

Comment: Does the query work if you hard-code values into it an run it in MySQL directly either through PHPmyAdmin or the MySQL Workbench??

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If I take out the JOIN in the sub query, yes

Comment: I *think* what you are looking for is a `cross apply` join. Typically you use it in combination with a table valued function.

Comment: I just saw that comment after I posted

Comment: @Jondlm Do you have good link for it, reading the MySQL docs now but it is kind of vague

Comment: @Sammaye Let me see if I can put together a little example in SQL fiddle, I've never actually done a `cross apply` on MySql, my experience is with T-SQL :/

Comment: Whelp, he beat me to it, so never mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gordons answer is really close but I wanted it to return even if no data was found for tran_date so I changed my query to:

```
SELECT tbl_review.*, users.first_name, users.last_name, order_ns.tran_date
FROM tbl_review
LEFT JOIN users ON users.sequal_user_id = tbl_review.user_id 
LEFT JOIN order_ns ON order_ns.order_id = (
    SELECT order_ns.order_id 
    FROM order_ns
    LEFT JOIN product_2_order_ns on product_2_order_ns.external_order_id = order_ns.order_id
            WHERE product_2_order_ns.bkfno IN :id
    ORDER BY order_ns.tran_date ASC
    LIMIT 1
 ) 
 WHERE tbl_review.product_id IN :id AND tbl_review.approved = 1;
```

This will return the distinct data of `tran_date` irrespective of whether it is found or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a correlated subquery.  It is unclear exactly what the relationship is between the inner query and the outer one.  My guess is that it is on users and orders:

```
SELECT tbl_review.*, users.first_name, users.last_name,
       (SELECT order_ns.tran_date 
        FROM order_ns LEFT JOIN
             product_2_order_ns
             on product_2_order_ns.external_order_id = order_ns.order_id and
                product_2_order_ns.bkfno = tbl_review.product_id and
        WHERE order_ns.user_id = tbl_review.user_id
        ORDER BY order_ns.trandate ASC 
        LIMIT 1
       ) as purchase_date
FROM tbl_review LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON users.sequal_user_id = tbl_review.user_id
WHERE tbl_review.product_id IN :id AND tbl_review.approved = 1;
```

EDIT:

Oh, the inner query *has* no relationship to the outer query.  Then it is easier.  Move it to the `from` clause using `cross join`:

```
SELECT tbl_review.*, users.first_name, users.last_name,
       innerquery.tran_date as purchase_date
FROM tbl_review LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON users.sequal_user_id = tbl_review.user_id cross join
     (SELECT order_ns.tran_date 
      FROM order_ns LEFT JOIN
           product_2_order_ns
           on product_2_order_ns.external_order_id = order_ns.order_id 
      WHERE product_2_order_ns.bkfno IN :id
      ORDER BY order_ns.trandate ASC 
      LIMIT 1
     ) innerquery
WHERE tbl_review.product_id IN :id AND tbl_review.approved = 1;
```

Comment: That is the thing the inner query has no relation to the outer query, it is basically an extra piece of data I would like to get back without having to do another query from PHP, I'll try this and see if it works

Comment: Nah it won't take the JOIN, I remember MySQL blocking JOINs in sub queries for some reason or another, I got more and more of a feeling I will have to make this two queries

Comment: @Sammaye . . . See the edited answer.  I didn't understand the question.

Comment: That is so close, just gotta find a way to make it optional now, so that it will return the review even if there is not join onto the sub query, hmm